# SQL query: combine 2 tables with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with combining 2 tables. It is possible to combine 2 tables with this values?

table 1:

```
id no.    descrp      value
1          A        10
3          C        30
5          E        50
```

table 2:

```
id no.    descrp
1         A
2         B
3         C
4         D
5         E
```

Results:

```
id no.    descrp    value
1         A         10
2         B         null/0
3         C         30
4         D         null/0
5         E         50
```

I already try to join 2 tables but result can't display the null values.

Comment: Search for `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `Left Outer Join` which selects all the data from table positioned at left hand side and find equivalent match data in table position at right hand side. If there is a match then it returns the data else it populates a `NULL`. Here you go..

```
SELECT t2.[id no], t2.Descrption, t1.amount
FROM table2 t2
Left outer join table1 t1 on t2.[id no]= t1.[id no]
```

**EDIT** - to replace `NULL` with **0**, use following query.

```
SELECT t2.[id no], t2.Descrption, COALESCE(t1.amount,0) FROM table2 t2 Left outer join table1 t1 on t2.[id no]= t1.[id no]
```

Comment: @aoy24 try this.... SELECT t2.[id no], t2.Descrption, COALESCE(t1.amount,0)
FROM table2 t2
Left outer join table1 t1 on t2.[id no]= t1.[id no]

Comment: @AmneshGoel Please edit your answer to your answer in the comment ;).